# Opacity value is ignored in html2canvas when the image is downloaded

Tags: javascript, html, css, opacity, html2canvas

I have used figure property to set the background image and one image using IMG tag inside that figure tag. I am using html2canvas function to download it. I have an issue with opacity. It works fine if I set the opacity for the main card and download it. But if I set the opacity for another image which is in IMG tag, in the browser it shows perfect, but when downloaded it gives 100% opacity. Please check the attached images.

[image]
[image]